# How to add parameter's id to link at controller method with using ajax in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I get parameters with using ajax. At this point there is no problem but how to add parameter id's with giving a link at the Controller Method. Because I want to display a link at the view and when I click that link I want to route another view with parameter's id

Here is my controller:

```
public string corporate()
        {

            var management = "";
            var management_id=""; ? How can I add this paremeter to link to route another View with this parameter
            foreach (var query in db.corporate)
            {

                management =management + "<li><input type='checkbox'/><label>"+query.person_position+"</label></li>";
            }
            return (management);
        }
```

you know MVC has @Html.Actionlink() tag and I can't add so how can I add parameter id  with using ajax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]    
public ActionResult MyAction(string id){

}



<a href="/controlle/myaction/1234">Link</a>
```

You can simply do a get request, make sure to name your parameter id and pass value this way.

Comment: Yes I found before you wrote answer:) but anyway thank you very much

Comment: Its the easiest and cleanest way, also you can do the same with .post, just make sure to change action attribute to [HttpPost]

Answer (score 1):

You can add some parameters in @Url.Action, such as:

```
@Url.Action( "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { parameterId = Model.Id } )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is not usefull for me because of using ajax I wanna share my solution